# SubQuery related

Tags: sql, rdbms

If inner subquery returns zero rows then what will be  the answer? No rows return, outer query result will be shown, error…

Answer (score 1):

In scalar context the subquery will return:

- `NULL` if `0` rows returned
- The value returned if `1` row returned
- An error if `2` or more rows returned.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you are using the subquery for. If it's to display data, the result of the subquery will be `null`. If you are using it for an inner join, then the join operation will return no rows.